# Why doesnt this simple jQuery transfer effect work?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-effects

I've included the jQuery UI stuff that I need and the jQuery core but still the following wont work:

```
<div id="a" style="width: 500px; height: 500px; background-color: #F00; border: 1px solid #00F;">Click me</div>
<div id="b" style="width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color: #0F0; border: 1px solid #00F;"></div>
```

And

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#a').click(function () { 
        $(this).effect(
            'transfer', 
            { to: $('#b') }, 
            1000
        ); 
    });
});​
```

You can find a JSFiddle example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/EUSyz/)

Comment: @Bondye did you read the question? *I've included the jQuery UI stuff that I need*

Comment: I THINK I have set up the JSFiddle for this correctly! I initially did that to ensure that it wasnt some required jQuery that I'd left out...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/EUSyz/3/ I simply added the CSS line for .ui-effects-transfer to your HTML and it worked straight away?

Comment: @Gavin - thanks, my custom download of jQuery UI just omitted that from the bundled CSS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For effect you need jQuery UI

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css " />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js "></script> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js "></script>
```

Also you need the transfer css like

> .ui-effects-transfer { border: 2px dotted gray; }

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/4JUdY/1/)

Comment: ROFL - I downloaded a custom build of jQuery UI (selecting only what I needed but made sure of `effects core` and `transfer` effect) and for some reason, the CSS it came with simply omitted the `.ui-effects-transfer` style (!?)

Comment: how to stop a transfer effect ?